# Export all Schema and CT list to excel

Tags: content-manager, data-migration

There is a design change request for our website. Hence we require data as to how many components will be affected with the change in an existing schema or how many total pages were using a component CT.

Is there any way with which I can export all data related to a number of schema and CTs and corresponding components and pages using those in excel sheet?

Answer (score 3):

There is a Alchemy plugin on the store
https://www.alchemywebstore.com/plugins/Document-Creator

It generates .docx file.
Supported items: schema, pt, ct, tbb

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look at Mark Richardson's **sdl-tridion-core-service-samples** library here:
https://bitbucket.org/spiderbike/sdl-tridion-core-service-samples/src/master/

In particular, he has a **Count components per schema.linq** script that reports on how many Components are based on each Schema in the system:
https://bitbucket.org/spiderbike/sdl-tridion-core-service-samples/src/master/Examples/Components/Count%20components%20per%20schema.linq

In the script, he uses a `RepositoryItemsFilterData` filter to get all of the Schemas in a given Publication, and then a `UsingItemsFilterData` filter to get all of the Components that are using each Schema.

That library, along with the **Core Service Recipes** in the Tridion Cookbook, should give you a good start:
https://github.com/TridionPractice/tridion-practice/wiki/CookbookDocumentation#core-service-recipies

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this quite easily in PowerShell, using the [Tridion PowerShell Modules](https://github.com/pkjaer/tridion-powershell-modules).

Following is a small script to return all of the Components currently using a given Schema:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string] $SchemaId
)

$client = Get-TridionCoreServiceClient;
$filter = New-Object Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.UsingItemsFilterData;
$filter.ItemTypes = 'Component';
$filter.IncludedVersions = 'OnlyLatestVersions';

$items = $client.GetList($SchemaId, $filter);
Write-Output $items;
```

If you save that as WhereUsed.ps1, you can call it like so:

```
.\WhereUsed.ps1 tcm:13-954-8
```

It returns the objects, so you can easily pipe that into other cmdlets.

For instance, if you only want the ID and Title of all of the Components, you do this:

```
.\WhereUsed.ps1 tcm:13-954-8 | Select Id,Title
```

And finally, if you want to view that in Excel or another text editor, you could export it to CSV like this:

```
.\WhereUsed.ps1 tcm:13-954-8 | Select Id,Title | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path 'ComponentsUsingSchema.csv'
```

Isn't PowerShell great? :)